# Text message function returns error on device

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sms

I am retrieving the phone number from my Firebase database, no matter how I enter it into the database it returns an error on my device:

> "Message sent to  invalid destination. Please check your number and try again. Msg 2127"

The message comes in as an automatic reply immediately after the text is sent out. I have tried entering it into firebase as `111-111-1111` and `1111111111` (not actually using a number 1 but a real phone number).

The calling function works fine however the same number being texted is not working.

```
var contact: Int!
@IBAction func textButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if canSendText() {
          if let contactopt = contact{
            var messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        messageVC.recipients = ["tel:\(contactopt)"]
        messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;

            self.present(messageVC, animated: false, completion: nil)}}
    else {
        let errorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Cannot Send Text Message", message: "Your device is not able to send text messages.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        errorAlert.show()
    }

}


func canSendText() -> Bool {
    return MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()
}

func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {

    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


 @IBAction func callButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if let contactopt = contact{

    if let url = NSURL(string: "tel://\(contactopt)") {
    //    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
        UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change 
  messageVC.recipients = ["tel:(contactopt)"]

messageVC.recipients = [String(contactopt)]